# Get Specified row index of a column from a data table having values contained in a string

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, linq-to-dataset

I have a data table having the two columns Select and Value.

```
Select Value
 0      213
 0      314
 0      282
```

I have an integer array called Ids={213,314}
If the values of Ids occur in the data table column "values" then update the "select" 
column as 1.
I have to do this using Linq. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq is for querying, not for updating. So you have to do task in two steps. First is querying for rows which should be updated:

```
var rows = from r in table.AsEnumerable()
           where Ids.Contains(r.Field<int>("Value"))
           select r;
// Or lambda syntax
// rows = table.AsEnumerable().Where(r => Ids.Contains(r.Field<int>("Value")))
```

Second part is updating selected rows, which does not involve Linq:

```
foreach(var row in rows)
    row.SetField("Select", 1);
```